# Create a long format considering specific enteties

Tags: r, dplyr, long-integer

I have a data set where some variables refer to a specific entity. All other variables have no relationship with those entities.

Here is an example:

```
library(dplyr)

d = samp %>%
  select(matches("Q2|Q8")) 

glimpse(d)

Observations: 10
Variables: 23
$ Q2    <dbl> 7, 6, 6, 9, 3, 3, 3, 3, 8, 5
$ Q8ar1 <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1
$ Q8ar2 <dbl> 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1
$ Q8ar3 <dbl> 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
$ Q8ar4 <dbl> 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0
$ Q8ar5 <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
$ Q8br1 <dbl> 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 2, NA, NA, 6, 5
$ Q8br2 <dbl> 6, NA, NA, NA, 1, 6, 6, NA, 6, 6
$ Q8br3 <dbl> 6, 6, NA, 6, 6, 3, 6, 6, 4, 4
$ Q8br4 <dbl> 6, 6, NA, 6, NA, 6, NA, 6, 6, NA
$ Q8cr1 <dbl> 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1
$ Q8cr2 <dbl> 5, NA, NA, NA, 1, 4, 2, NA, 2, 3
$ Q8cr3 <dbl> 5, 5, NA, 5, 2, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1
$ Q8cr4 <dbl> 5, 4, NA, 5, NA, 4, NA, 5, 2, NA
$ Q8dr1 <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 2, NA, NA, NA, 6
$ Q8dr2 <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
$ Q8dr3 <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, 6, 6
$ Q8dr4 <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
$ Q8er1 <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA
$ Q8er2 <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
$ Q8er3 <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA
$ Q8er4 <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
$ Q8f   <dbl> 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 3
```

Variable Q2 doesn't belong to an entity. Q8a to Q8e belongs to an entity, Q8F not. The variables Q8a to Q8e which ends with 1 belong to entity 1, those which ends with 2 belong to entity 2 and so on. The one which ends with 5 (Q8ar5) doesn´t belong to an entity (e.g. Q8ar5 should be treated like Q2 or Q8f). The goal is to transform the data into a long format considering the entities. For now, I did it this way:

First, I create the entity variables and then I remove the ending of the variables. The result is 4 data sets that are identical in the "non_entity" variables but contain the variables for each entity.

```
E1 = d %>%
      mutate(E = "E1")%>%
      mutate(E = as.factor(E)) %>%
      select(-matches("^Q8a.*(2|3|4)$")) %>%
      select(-matches("^Q8b.*(2|3|4)$")) %>%
      select(-matches("^Q8c.*(2|3|4)$")) %>%
      select(-matches("^Q8d.*(2|3|4)$")) %>%
      select(-matches("^Q8e.*(2|3|4)$")) %>%
      rename_at(vars(matches("^Q8(a|b|c|d|e)")), ~str_remove(., "(1|2|3|4)$"))



E2 = d %>%
  mutate(E = "E2") %>%
  mutate(E = as.factor(E)) %>%
  select(-matches("^Q8a.*(1|3|4)$")) %>%
  select(-matches("^Q8b.*(1|3|4)$")) %>%
  select(-matches("^Q8c.*(1|3|4)$")) %>%
  select(-matches("^Q8d.*(1|3|4)$")) %>%
  select(-matches("^Q8e.*(1|3|4)$")) %>%
  rename_at(vars(matches("^Q8(a|b|c|d|e)")), ~str_remove(., "(1|2|3|4)$"))


E3 = d %>%
  mutate(E = "E3") %>%
  mutate(E = as.factor(E)) %>%
  select(-matches("^Q8a.*(1|2|4)$")) %>%
  select(-matches("^Q8b.*(1|2|4)$")) %>%
  select(-matches("^Q8c.*(1|2|4)$")) %>%
  select(-matches("^Q8d.*(1|2|4)$")) %>%
  select(-matches("^Q8e.*(1|2|4)$")) %>%
  rename_at(vars(matches("^Q8(a|b|c|d|e)")), ~str_remove(., "(1|2|3|4)$"))

E4 = d %>%
  mutate(E = "E") %>%
  mutate(E = as.factor(E)) %>%
  select(-matches("^Q8a.*(1|2|3)$")) %>%
  select(-matches("^Q8b.*(1|2|3)$")) %>%
  select(-matches("^Q8c.*(1|2|3)$")) %>%
  select(-matches("^Q8d.*(1|2|3)$")) %>%
  select(-matches("^Q8e.*(1|2|3)$")) %>%
  rename_at(vars(matches("^Q8(a|b|c|d|e)")), ~str_remove(., "(1|2|3|4)$"))
```

Then, I bind those data frames in order to create the long format.

```
E_all = do.call("rbind", list(E1, E2, E3, E4))
```

The result looks like this, which is fine.

```
glimpse(E_all) 

Observations: 40
Variables: 9
$ Q2    <dbl> 7, 6, 6, 9, 3, 3, 3, 3, 8, 5, 7, 6, 6, 9, 3, 3, 3, 3, 8, 5, 7, 6, 6, 9, 3, 3, 3, 3, 8, 5, 7,…
$ Q8ar  <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,…
$ Q8ar5 <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
$ Q8br  <dbl> 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 2, NA, NA, 6, 5, 6, NA, NA, NA, 1, 6, 6, NA, 6, 6, 6, 6, NA, 6, 6, 3, 6, 6, 4…
$ Q8cr  <dbl> 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, 5, NA, NA, NA, 1, 4, 2, NA, 2, 3, 5, 5, NA, 5, 2, 1, 1, 5, 1…
$ Q8dr  <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 2, NA, NA, NA, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, …
$ Q8er  <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,…
$ Q8f   <dbl> 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 3, 5,…
$ E     <fct> Smava, Smava, Smava, Smava, Smava, Smava, Smava, Smava, Smava, Smava, Finanzcheck, Finanzche…
```

However, this is a really simple case. There could be 20 Entities a lot more variables. Is there a way to do this with less code (e.g. by the gather function)?  Thanks for any advice.

Here is a small dput:

```
structure(list(record = structure(c(1227, 780, 480, 111, 1888, 
1602, 1800, 1322, 1474, 755), format.spss = "F7.0", display_width = 7L), 
    Q1 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2), Q2 = c(7, 6, 6, 9, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 8, 5), Q3 = c(3, 8, 4, 7, 7, 4, 7, 6, 7, 7), 
    ort = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Q13 = c(4, 6, 4, 3, 
    5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 6), Q5r1 = c(4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2), 
    Q5r2 = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3), Q5r3 = c(4, 4, 4, 
    4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4), Q5r4 = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 
    4), Q5r5 = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4), Q8ar1 = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), Q8ar2 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 1), Q8ar3 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Q8ar4 = c(1, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), Q8ar5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), Q8br1 = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 2, NA, NA, 6, 5), Q8br2 = c(6, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1, 6, 6, NA, 6, 6), Q8br3 = c(6, 6, NA, 6, 6, 
    3, 6, 6, 4, 4), Q8br4 = c(6, 6, NA, 6, NA, 6, NA, 6, 6, NA
    ), Q8cr1 = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1), Q8cr2 = c(5, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1, 4, 2, NA, 2, 3), Q8cr3 = c(5, 5, NA, 5, 2, 
    1, 1, 5, 1, 1), Q8cr4 = c(5, 4, NA, 5, NA, 4, NA, 5, 2, NA
    ), Q8dr1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 2, NA, NA, NA, 6), Q8dr2 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q8dr3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, 6, 6), Q8dr4 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), Q8er1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), Q8er2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q8er3 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q8er4 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), Q8f = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 3
    ), Q9 = c(2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1), Q10r1 = c(NA, 1, 
    1, NA, 0, 1, NA, 1, 0, 1), Q10r2 = c(NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 
    NA, 0, 0, 0), Q10r3 = c(NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 1, NA, 0, 0, 0), 
    Q10r4 = c(NA, 0, 0, NA, 1, 1, NA, 0, 1, 0), Q10r5 = c(NA, 
    0, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0), Q10r6 = c(NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 
    0, NA, 0, 0, 0), Q10r7 = c(NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 
    0), Q10r8 = c(NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0), Q10r9 = c(NA, 
    0, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0), Q10r10 = c(NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 
    1, NA, 0, 0, 0), Q10r11 = c(NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 
    0), Q10r12 = c(NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0), Q10r13 = c(NA, 
    0, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0), Q11 = c(2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 
    1, 3, 1), Q12 = c(3, 2, 3, 5, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2), Q14 = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1), Q15 = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 
    4, 2, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: The E5 should be treated like the Q2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `pivot_longer` here

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

out1 <- samp %>%
         select(matches("^(Q2|Q8)")) %>%
         mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
         pivot_longer(cols = -c(rn, Q2, Q8f), names_to = c(".value", "Q8"), 
            names_sep = "(?<=[a-z])(?=[1-5]$)", values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(E = str_c('E', rowid(rn))) %>%
    arrange(E)
```